# Use of artifactory.download not working for snapshot version in Salt-stack

Tags: artifactory, salt-stack

I use saltstack to deploy my application on AWS. The formulas fetch the jar from artifactory and run the application as a service.

It works fine for production(release version ex: 1.1.3) but it fails on dev environment with snapshot version (ex: 1.1.4-SNAPSHOT).

My formula :

```
artifactory.downloaded:
   - artifact:
        artifactory_url: {{ artifactory_url }}
        repository: {{ repository }}
        artifact_id: {{ artifact_id }}
        group_id: {{ group_id }}
        packaging: {{ packaging }}
        classifier: {{ classifier }}
        version: '{{ version }}'
   - target_dir: {{ folder }}
```

The error: `'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figure it out.

The state `artifactory.downloaded` use the module `artifactory.get_snapshot` for snapshot and `artifactory.get_release` for release.

The `get_snapshot` module needs a `snapshot_version` properties and `version` properties (I think it's an issue) but you can't pass `snapshot_version` properties from `artifactory.downloaded` state.

So to resolve this issue, I don't longer use `artifactory.downloaded` state but `artifactory.get_snapshot / artifactory.get_release` module :

```
artifact_download:
 module.run:
    - name: artifactory.get_snapshot
    - artifactory_url: {{ artifactory_url }}
    - repository: {{ repository }}
    - artifact_id: {{artifact_id }}
    - group_id: {{ group_id }}
    - packaging: {{ packaging }}
    - classifier: {{ classifier }}
    - version: '{{ version }}'
    - snapshot_version: '{{ version }}'
    - target_dir: {{ folder }}
```

⚠️  - `snapshot_version` and `version` properties are both required.

Comment: You can just specify version: 'latest-snapshot'  to get the most recent snapshot version, see https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.artifactory.html